# Mysql row format compressed what are the drawbacks?

Tags: mysql

The mysql manual is all go for compression using `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` but I noticed I can also set a key block size value.

What various effects does this have disregarding the actual compression of the file size.

Example

```
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 2
```

And

```
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 4
```

Above both compresses at different sizes but are there any drawbacks using on or the other?

Answer (score 1):

There is one obvious problem: less block size = less performance, especially in OLTP applications.

The interesting thing is that for tables with InnoDB, lower block size does **not** mean smaller compressed table.

You should read how it works: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-internals.html
or check every possible value from 1 to 16 :)